# Wordpress grid shows empty entries

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a grid in wordpress. But sometimes I get empty entries. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5uOW.png)

```
<div class="row">
    <?php

    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

              ?>

                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <?php $kale_entry = 'small'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); ?>
                  </div>
                <?php
        endwhile;

    }?>
```

Do you have any ideas, why is that happening? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what were the results of thes attempts?

Comment: Still new to stackoverflow. Here my code:                                            <div class="row">
    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();       
              ?>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <?php $kale_entry = 'small'; include(locate_template('parts/entry.php')); ?>
                  </div>
                <?php
        endwhile;
    }?>

Comment: It is a styling issue since the first column height is not same as the other column, so it is floating to the right side.

Comment: set `min-height:500px` for this div `col-md-4`

Comment: Thank you PrakashSingh, @George but it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: set `min-height:600px` for this div `col-md-4`. increase the min-height

Comment: @George Thank you very much! It worked:)

Answer (score 0):

set 'min-height:600px' for this div 'col-md-4'. increase the min-height  and check.